# I keep getting a "ArrayIndexOutOfBounds" Exception when using String.split

Tags: java, string, file-io

I am writing this class for another program and I keep getting an Array out of bounds exception when I am splitting the string **str**.

```
    static String[][] readFile(){
    BufferedReader in;
    count = 0;
    String[][] ret = new String[20][2];
    try
    {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(CFGfolder+"\\input.ini"));
        String str;

        while((str=in.readLine()) != null){
            if(str!="[GameEvents]"){
                ret[count][0]=str.split("=")[0];
                ret[count][1]=str.split("=")[1];
                count++;
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ret;

}
```

This is the format of the file it is reading.

```
evtCastSpell1=[q]
evtCastSpell2=[w]
evtCastSpell3=[e]
evtCastSpell4=[r]
```

I tried seeing what the **str** string really is (meaning, print it without the splitting) and it shows that it is correctly reading the file and putting it in the array. The problem comes when I try to read the **[1]** of the splitted string. The **[0]** is fine and it correctly prints

```
evtCastSpell1
evtCastSpell2
evtCastSpell3
evtCastSpell4
```

I really have no idea why it is not reading the **[1]** part. Usually this kinds of errors come from regex expressions, is it understanding the **[** in the second part as a regex expression? How would I get around that if so? I've tried looking around but all I can find is similar errors that happen because of regex expressions. Is this one the same?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: not what you asked but you should use `new FileReader(new File(CFGfolder, "input.ini"))` to avoid platform specific coding.

Comment: you also could probably do `ret[count]=str.split("=");` to avoid doing split twice.

Comment: While the reason of the exception, and correct code is given in sudmong's answer, Your code can have other problems too. If count exceeds the array size 20, then there will also be an arrayindexoutofboundexception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a reference equality comparison instead of a string `equals()` comparison:

I would do this:

```
while((str=in.readLine()) != null){
    if(!"[GameEvents]".equals(str)) {
        String[] splits = str.split("=");
        ret[count][0]=splits[0];
        ret[count][1]=splits[1];
        count++;
    }
}
```

The reason of you `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is because of this:

```
if(str!="[GameEvents]"){
```

Because of the reference equality, the `if` expression returns a `true` and you're doing a `split()` on the value `[GameEvents]`.

I hope this helps:

- More insight: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus).

Comment: +1. Elite, why `ret[count][1]=str.split("=")[1];` is not working? any idea?

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot that Strings have to be compared as objects. Me be dumb :p

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the exception could be the number of lines in file going more than the size of your array.
Also replace this `if(str!="[GameEvents]")` with `if(!str.equals("[GameEvents]"))` for getting correct results.

Comment: I don't see how that's the problem. The issue is that the array str.split("=")[1] doesn't exist. The issue is that the array being created by the split is length 1, so only the [0] element exists. So the question is, why is that?

Comment: See my answer, reason for exception could be "could be the number of lines in file going more than the size of your array" . And for If condition see @The Elite Gentleman's answer